# comparing a variable in when oracle sql

Tags: oracle, variable

I want to use a variable in when clause of oracle sql like below

```
DEFINE balancing_id = 0--'16493'--null;
ON A.BALANCING_ID = 
CASE
    WHEN &balancing_id is null-- &balancing_id = ''--balancing_id>0
    THEN B.BALANCING_ID 
    ELSE &balancing_id
END
```

But I get the error below :

```
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

this line:

> WHEN &balancing_id is null-- &balancing_id = ''--balancing_id>0

UPDATE:

> WHEN 1 = 1

works as expected

How to use variable like this?

Comment: You have to use a dynamic sql

Comment: @RohitGupta is this for oracle sql? can you give example i havent used this one yet

Comment: You do not need to use dynamic sql. The syntax works for me. Can you provide your version of oracle and the full query? Looks to me like your case statement is part of a join statement?

Answer (score 0):

Consider what will happen in the case where `&balancing_id` is null. The SQL condition will be evaluated as

```
WHEN  is null
```

If it's possible for `&balancing_id` to be null, then you will have to either set it to the word `null` or else treat it as a quoted string and then convert it to a number explicitly.

```
SQL> define balancing_id = null
SQL>
SQL> set verify on
SQL>
SQL> select count(*) from dual where &balancing_id = 0;
old   1: select count(*) from dual where &balancing_id = 0
new   1: select count(*) from dual where null = 0

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

or

```
SQL> define balancing_id = ''
SQL>
SQL> define balancing_id
DEFINE BALANCING_ID    = "" (CHAR)
SQL>

SQL> select count(*) from dual where to_number('&balancing_id') = 0;
old   1: select count(*) from dual where to_number('&balancing_id') = 0
new   1: select count(*) from dual where to_number('') = 0

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```